# How long should I wait for an e-mail when applied for an internship

Tags: job-search, email, internship

I am a student and applied for internship in 4-5 companies few days ago. But, I haven't received any response so far. So, my questions are:

- How many day should I wait for an E-Mail before assuming they are not interested in me?
- If I don't got any reply even after considerable time, should I E-Mail them again asking for a reply?

Comment: Sending out emails to a few companies isn't sufficient for anything - most likely none of them will respond.  An HR department could get hundreds of those toward the beginning of a new semester.  A professor might be able to tell you something about particularly good prospects.  Try to find someone that knows something about the needs of these organizations.

Comment: Applying with just an email, without a formal cv etc, will most likely result in nothing more but being ignored. 
And you should never include weekends. Companys think in 'working days'.

Comment: imho you should always attach something "hr-compliant" like a formal cv. Just to show them that you are able to create such a document.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer your question not opinion-based.

Comment: I agree with @MeredithPoor. When I was unemployed I sent a lot of e-mails. 10 months has passed and I never got a single "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you like to apply for job or an intern role you have to manage lot of companies at th same time, at least 30-100 but it depends on the market and your skill-set (when I was looking for a role I sent around 1000 CVs through 2-3 months ). So first step could be the e-mail but after that you should use another type of sites\communities\job portals as well. Another source could be the offline events when you find lot of good opportunities but I think one of the best source is the private network. If I were you I am using the mixture of these.

If you don't get feedback in a month I think you can send another questioning e-mail but a lot of times the departments which are dealing with your case are really busy and haven't enough time to response immediately or later. I think you could boost your heat rate with a well edited CV\cover letter and title as well. In additional you are a developer and be creative when you send an application. You find a lot of good pointers about this in forums and recruitment related topics.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the company. As mentioned earlier, some companies receive hundreds of applications each day and might not have the time to reply to each applicant. (But there are also those who do reply!). Some advice I received before was:

1.) It's okay to send an email for an update.
2.) Apply to as many companies as you can. If you get a lot of offers, then you can always say "no".

Good luck!

Comment: Please make sure to include as much rationale behind your points as possible.

Comment: Hello and welcome to The Workplace SE. Our Q&A site put in place some [back it up](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/123/should-we-add-a-back-it-up-rule-to-the-faq-now) guidelines to help get the best answers. Can you [edit] your post to include references or relate this to a personal experience. Also, be sure to answer the full question. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

- How many day should I wait for an E-Mail before assuming they are not interested in me?

Zero. In fact, zero minutes. Immediately after you have applied, forget it, and move on to apply to next company. By "forget it" I mean that you previous applications should not stop you in any way proceeding with other applications. Your success depends very much on volume, the more companies you apply to, the better changes you have to find one that is interested in you.

Also, "forget it" in a sense, that you don't dwell on it, especially with cases where you don't get any response or get a rejection.

However, "forget it" does not mean, that you should not make follow up:

- If I don't got any reply even after considerable time, should I E-Mail them again asking for a reply?

Yes. Call or email, but do understand that companies do get a lot of internship applications and might not be very responsive no matter what.